# Cannot connect to hidden services

Tags: onion-services, error

In the past few days, I faced a problem that never occurred to me before: when trying to access .onion sites, the page times out after trying to connect. This is what it says:

> Unable to connect
>   Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at --------.onion.
>   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
>       If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
>       If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web. "

And several lines of the message below is what it's shown in the log :

```
mar 07 16:33:27.965 [Notifica] Closing stream for '[scrubbed].onion': hidden service is unavailable (try again later).
```

Can anyone help me? I'm kind of a beginner and don't know much about Tor settings and options, so I hope someone can help me understand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: now it shows also this within the log:

mar 12 23:03:09.144 [Avvertimento] Rejecting SOCKS request for anonymous connection to private address [scrubbed].

Comment: Is this a problem you face with one particular onion site, or with all onion sites?

Comment: All sites, even the most frequented ones

Comment: Is your clock accurate, including timezone?

Comment: how can i check if the tie is ok? BTW in the log there wasnt anything regarding the timezone

Comment: And the strange thing is that i just entered the hidden wiki and it works, but if i try any other site (previously checked with onionup) it says "cant extablish connection with..."